# Rename a table, then create a table with the same name in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I had a table called 'User' in Oracle
I renamed it to 'Account' using the below command. This was successful.

```
RENAME User TO Account
```

I then want to create a new table called 'User' with different columns. I tried the following command,

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    user_id    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
    user_name  VARCHAR2(25)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
;
```

But Oracle does not allow me to do so. I get the following error,

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE User(
    user_id    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
    user_name  VARCHAR2(25)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What could be the issue? Do I need to run any other command after renaming a table to clear some cache etc.

**Edit:**

Constraints were renamed successfully after renaming the table

```
ALTER TABLE Account RENAME CONSTRAINT PK_User TO PK_Account
```

NOTE: The table names 'Account' and 'User' are used just for example purpose. I understand that 'User' is a reserved keyword.

Comment: User is an Oracle reserved word. You cannot use it for a table name.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your primary key name is already taken. You should rename it:

```
ALTER INDEX "PK_User" RENAME TO "PK_Account_User";
```

You can check which names are already taken with the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME='<table_name>';
```

Comment: I had already renamed the constraint using 'ALTER TABLE Account RENAME CONSTRAINT PK_User TO PK_Account'. The second command you provided 'SELECT * FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME='User' gave me no results.

Comment: I did an ALTER INDEX as suggested and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

user is a reserved word.

```
KLRICE@xe >CREATE TABLE User(
  2      user_id    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
  3      user_name  VARCHAR2(25)     NOT NULL,
  4      CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
  5  );

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE User(
    user_id    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
    user_name  VARCHAR2(25)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
Error report -
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Use a prefix or another word

```
1  CREATE TABLE my_user (
  2      user_id    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
  3      user_name  VARCHAR2(25)     NOT NULL,
  4      CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
  5* );
KLRICE@xe >/

Table MY_USER created.

KLRICE@xe >
```

Comment: I have used 'User' and 'Account' just as an example

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    user_id    NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
    user_name  VARCHAR2(25)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_User_id PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle tells you: "name is already used by an existing object" then find out what object has that name.

```
select owner,object_type
from all_objects where 
object_name='<NAME_OF_OBJECT>'
```